# What is this called, PCB bevelled fingers?

Tags: connector, pcb-fabrication

I found this non-plated fingers PCB connector, with blackish color, in a Logitech MK240 wireless keyboard. This fingers connect between the PCB and plastic sheets wiring (for the keys).

[image: PCB fingers]

It is a bit beveled, or I'd say *furrowed* (black has more bevel than grey in the pic), as to enable the center of an individual finger to give more pressure to the sheets I thought.

What are these fingers specifically called, especially when requesting fabrication? Are these fingers replaceable with usual PCB traces beveled with solder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this falls under a 'gold finger' process step. You would communicate to your manufacturer that you need beveled gold fingers, and sometimes you can even specify the exact amount in a mechanical layer or additional mechanical drawing file.

This is not to be confused with V-grooves, which are a separate process, and a way of singulating individual PCBs from a panel.

In this specific case, they seemed to have gone for carbon instead of gold. My guess would be that since this process already had a carbon layer added for rubber-dome keys (as this is a keyboard), and thus they used that for cost. The reason they use gold in other cases is to avoid contact issues due to oxidation. The same can be achieved with carbon contacts.

I don't think there is any specific process name for this.

Comment: It's not gold. It's more like carbon. I had a question when I tried to remove it. See [soldering-to-pcb-edge-connector-coated-for-fpc-contact](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/230225/soldering-to-pcb-edge-connector-coated-for-fpc-contact).

Comment: I clarified my answer @Transistor

Comment: Thanks, Joren. The carbon fingers are just for connection to the flexible PCB for the keyboard. There were no buttons on mine and I think we can see almost the whole PCB in the OP's photo. It's a kind of strange setup. I would have been nervous bringing it to the boss and recommending that we launch product with this type of connector!

Comment: Huh, odd that they do it that way. Only reason I can imagine is if they are using the same 'tech' of a different keyboard that maybe did have carbon printing? Or would it really be that much cheaper to go for carbon fingers? I guess every fraction of a cent counts if you are making millions of products!

Comment: Or on second thought, maybe the carbon printing allows for increased thickness, which gives them more flexibility with the mechanical tolerance of whatever keeps the two PCBs aligned and on top of each other?

Answer (score 0):

“Carbon ink printing” will likely get the idea across.