# Not detecting closed circuit in Goldtouch keyboard key presses

Tags: keyboard, fpc

### Context

While converting the Goldtouch Go!2 Mobile keyboard from Bluetooth to micro USB, I'm experiencing some difficulties in registering the keystroke signals coming out of the FPC connector.

### Setup

I bought:

- [A 20 pins FPC female input](https://www.conrad.nl/p/wurth-elektronik-68612014122-female-header-standaard-zif-fpc-totaal-aantal-polen-20-rastermaat-1-mm-1-stuks-708972?searchTerm=708972&searchType=suggest&searchSuggest=product)
- [A converter from 20 pins FPC to 20 holes](https://www.conrad.nl/p/adafruit-1325-adaptermodule-printplaat-leeg-1-stuks-1516592?searchTerm=1516592&searchType=suggest&searchSuggest=product)
- A Raspberry Pico
- 40 headers
- 20 cables

### Testing Code

The following MWE is used to test if a keystroke is registerred by the Pico in Thonny:

```
print("Hello World!")
import time
import digitalio
import board
print(board.board_id)

btn15_pin = board.GP15


btn15 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(btn15_pin)
btn15.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT
btn15.pull = digitalio.Pull.DOWN


while True:
    if btn15.value:
        print("button 15 pressed")
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

I verified it works by connecting the 3.3V output of the Pico to the GPIO15 pin. (the connection is registered when manually making contact, all the way up to the soldered FPC female input pins, however when extending the circuit to include the keyboard (strokes), it does not detect a closed circuit anymore).

### Observations/Testing

Basically I intend to connect the Pico through micro-USB to the pc, then connect a few keys from the keyboard coming out of the FPC via the converter to the GPIO pins of the Pico. To provide the keyboard with power/to close the circuit, I connect the 3.3V output of the Pico to the "ground/backplate" of the keyboard.

I wrote a small code that recognizes whether connections/closed circuits are found by the Pico. Here a closed circuit is a connection running from the 3.3V output of the Pico into for example GPIO pin 15. I verified the code on Thonny is able to recognize when such a circuit is made/closed. This verification is done because it prints "pin 15 is pressed" when the circuit is closed manually by just connecting a cable from the header of the 3.3V output into the header of pin GPIO15.

However, when I include the keyboard backplate in the circuit (input in the backplate and output through the FPC cable), I do not register a signal. Since I do not yet know the keymapping of the keyboard towards the FPC pin numbers I just tested pressing all the keys (one at a time), but nothing was registered when it was connected via the FPC-holes converter.

- However, when I connect that ground to a pin/FPC female input soldering pin, it does recognize the short/closed(circuit).
- So I am able to determine that the FPC output does not pass the current from the circuit backplate to the male FPC output cable.

[image: Overview Pico test circuit]
[image: FPC connection]

### Edit based on comments

After obtaining an Ohm meter, and testing the/some connection matrix between the pins (instead of connections from the ground/backplate to the pins). I found pressing the left part of the shift button creates a connection between 4th and 6th pin to the left of the 20 holes. So I could manually try the 20*20 (or 20*10) pin combinations, for each keyboard button, yielding (worst case) 20*20*+-40=1600 Ohm tests. However, I was wondering if there is a more intelligent way to do this.

### Question

How could I ensure the Pico is able to register the keypress signal via the FPC cable of the keyboard? (Note, I plugged the keyboard back into its original Bluetooth housing and verified it still works).

Comment: The keys are almost certainly wired as a matrix, where each key connects a row wire to a column wire. Start by using an ohmmeter to determine which two wires connect to a particular switch.

Comment: The assumption is that the keyboard matrix is resistive - it might very well be capacitive. If it is capacitive, then you'll not have much luck trying to detect a keypress using your current method.

Comment: @DaveTweed thank you! I was not familiar with the concept of keyboard matrices, and I was already wondering how they mapped so many inputs over a smaller number of pins. I found the left half of the shift key creates a connection between the 4th and 6th pin. So I can brute force test the combinations, or find a code that does that, if that's possible through the Pico.

Comment: I remember trying to fix one of those. They are a nightmare to disassemble, even destructively. I no longer use them because I went through one of them every year for 5 years. The key mechanism doesn't tolerate ingress of dust and small water droplets well. Same failure everytime in the same part of the keyboard.

Comment: @a.t. You may find my question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/230225/soldering-to-pcb-edge-connector-coated-for-fpc-contact) interesting although not entirely relevant to yours.